React/Spring Boot application API call is returning .jsx from the frontend instead of the expected data
I am using a decoupled React / Spring Boot application deployed on a single DigitalOcean Droplet. The application file structure is separated into a "backend" and "frontend" folder but it is all in the same repo. I was told that this is possible but it seems like my API calls are going to the frontend only for some reason.
I have the following API call in my frontend that is meant to return a list of services provided
const [ services, setServices ] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://my_application_domain/api/packages/load')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          const sortedServices = response.data.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
          setServices(sortedServices);
        } else
          console.log("nope")
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, [])

Please forgive my poor error handling. I just wanted to get something working. I will refactor later.
The issue is occurring with all of my API calls but since they are all very similar, I expect the issue is in the URL itself rather than some other aspect of the function
This API call used to have localhost:8080 instead of my domain but i changed it over after deployment. when i enter that URL in to my browser, i get a blank page as if I used a malformed <Route /> in my App.jsx it has a navbar and footer but no content. I tried logging the response which output .jsx instead of the expected data.
It would seem that my API is not hitting the backend and is instead hitting the frontend and returning .jsx but I'm not sure where to go to fix it. My only idea is that I need to configure DigitalOcean differently to account for the ports but I have never deployed a site before and I can't find a tutorial that is using the same stack as I am.
I've tried following about 6 different YT tutorials and searched SO for the solution but I keep getting stuck on one part or another. I would love to be able to say where exactly I got stuck but I got so frustrated with it that I set it all aside for a couple days and I no longer remember.

Your project, with a separation between frontend and backend within the same repository, is entirely feasible. However, when making API calls from the frontend, you need to pay attention to the proxy configuration to redirect those API requests to the backend.
In your React application, you can use a proxy configuration file to specify which API requests should be redirected to the backend. Make sure you've correctly configured the URL of the backend in this file.
For example, in the package.json file of your frontend, you can add a "proxy" section like this:
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"


Thanks for the answer @LEO! I added the proxy as you suggested and refactored my api calls to not include a domain. so the above api call url is now '/api/packages/load'. But I'm still getting the same result
